# Get nested values as type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider following type definition,

```
type Parent = {
   children: Child[]
}

type Child = {
   label: string
}

const parent: Parent = {
   children: [
       { label: 'label1' },
       { label: 'label2' }
   ]
}
```

Now, if I want to generate a genetic type, which contains the label values as key and value as any, is it possible to do it with generics? Do note that I am considering only compile time objects only.

```
type Labels = {
    label1: any,
    label2: any
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `Child` and `Parent` as generics type, where `K extends string` is used as generic constraint in order to correctly infer the string literal:

```
type Parent<K extends string> = {
   children: Child<K>[]
}

type Child<K extends string> = {
   label: K
}

type Labels<P extends Parent<any>> = P extends Parent<infer K>
  ? { [Key in K]: string } : never;
```

Then you can use an helper function in order to automatically infer the label keys from string literals (instead of typing them manually when defining `parent` as a value):

```
function Parent<K extends string>(parent: Parent<K>) {
  return parent;
}

const p1 = Parent({
   children: [
       { label: 'label1' },
       { label: 'label2' }
   ]
})
```

Now everything you need is an helper type that using inference and object mapping, transform the keys in the `Labels` type:

```
type Labels<P extends Parent<any>> = P extends Parent<infer K>
  ? { [Key in K]: string } : never;

type Labels1 = Labels<typeof p1>;

// Labels1 now is `{ label1: string; label2: string }`
```

See it in action @ [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=14&ssc=36&pln=13&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJwgO2AHgNJQgD2CgEwGcojgEBLZAcwD4oBeKAbwCgoOBjACwoBsCSZAC4oAYV4DMtANoBdVgF9WrUJHGSCmbHkIkylGvSZsOUPnABGEPqIxKVAMwCuyTsAoB7ZLEQp0WLj4yMSk5FR0ABRgfqii8EIBtACULOxQSMDOCD4xiQDcDqrg0AAyVjZEaDA6waEJ-mhwyCC0xrC1er6JaFSOEAhQGLTpAPwsUDIYECBQVENyogYRUIpQosgQAG4Dhayc3mRQYACMjN3+kaZcmkKiMulmHMzmFbZQAOQW1nwnH6sAGkeTxe3xsoi+bwATP9lGYFIpkio1GU3kQzkxyj8qijPI5jidaPkgA)